# Perl - "utime" is not exported by the Time::HiRes module

Tags: perl, time-hires

Getting this error when adding statement

```
use Time::HiRes qw( utime );
```

According to [Time::HiRes perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) it should be there, but it's not (looked in HiRes.pm). Does anybody know why? I am using perl 5.24.0, checked on several platforms (unix, win32).
Trying to set high resolution timestamps on my files. Is there any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `$Time::HiRes::VERSION`? First mention of `utime` in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Time-HiRes) is version 1.9735.

Comment: My perl 5.24.0 comes with Time::HiRes v1.9733 and produces the same error as your headline.

Comment: mob, same for me, 1.9733. Thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of Time::HiRes that predates the addition of `utime`. I'm not sure of the exact version in which `utime` was added, but it was after 1.9733 (2016-04-23) and no later than 1.9739 (2016-06-28). Upgrade Time::HiRes if you wish to use `utime`.